# Regex with case insensitive prefix

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a regex that's case insensitive prefix. I have the following but I am not sure whether that's correct or not:

```
String value1 = "97 ebt ue i ua so sufi iqc k";
String pattern1 = "(?=(\\b(?i:.*s.*)))(?=(\\b(?i:.*q.*)))";
```

In my example I am trying to find a match for `pattern1` in `value1`. As far as I understand:

1. `\\b` matches any word in the string
2. `:.*` and `.*` makes case insensitive

This works with some cases but with others fails. I can't figure out the issue.

**UPDATE:**

This case here returns true but it should return false. The thing is there should be any word that ends with `s` and another one that ends with `q` so since nothing ends with any of them so it should fail.

Comment: What is the output you are looking for? `\\b` is just a word boundary, it does not match a word. `(?i)` can be used n the beginning just once, and the whole pattern will be case insensitive.

Comment: What are the cases it works with and fails with. Can you give some examples?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Please post full relevant code.

Comment: Your regex doesn't say "word ends with `s` and another one that ends in `q`"  It says, "match a bunch of stuff followed by an `s` followed by a bunch more stuff followed by a `q` followed by a bunch more stuff".  Which your sample text does match.  You may want to investigate **word boundaries**

Comment: if you're looking for 'ends with s' and 'ends with q' then having .* on the end of each pattern group seems wrong, because you'll also match any word with s or q in the middle.

Comment: The .* before and after the s means it's case sensitive as well. so S is the same as s.

Comment: @omarsafwany: No, it doesn't. You should look into what regular expressions actually mean, instead of what they would mean if they were telepaths that could read your mind . . .

Answer (score 1):

The `\\b` construct is just a word boundary, it does not match a word.

`(?i)` can be used n the beginning just once, and the whole pattern will be case insensitive.

> The thing is there should be any word that ends with `s` and another one that ends with `q` so since nothing ends with any of them so it should fail

Use

```
(?Ui)^(?=.*s\\b)(?=.*q\\b)
```

Here, we have two anchored look-aheads requiring 2 words ending with `q` and `s` inside the input string (case-insensitive).

Here is the [code demo](http://ideone.com/U9gzrF):

```
String value1 = "97 ebts ue i ua so sufi iqc k";
String pattern1 = "(?Ui)^(?=.*s\\b)(?=.*q\\b)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(value1);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println("true");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

If you wonder what `?U` means it is just "fixing" the `\b` word boundary within Unicode strings. If you do not use any letters  other than Latin, you can remove the `U`.